# Finding extreme values using chain rule in multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

We are given the function
$$
  F(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)^2 - 2(x^2 - y^2)
$$

with the condition $F(x, y(x)) = 0$ for
$$
  y: (0, \sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto y(x)
$$

The objective is to compute all extreme points and classify them into max/min.
So far I've computed the partial derivatives and got an expression for $y'$
$$
\begin{align*}
  \partial_x F(x,y) &= 4x(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \\
  \partial_y F(x,y) &= 4y(x^2 + y^2 + 1)
\end{align*}
$$

So using the chain rule we get
$$
  y' = - \frac{\partial_x F(x, y(x))}{\partial_y F(x,y(x))} = - \frac{x(x^2 + [y(x)]^2 - 1)}{y(x) (x^2 + [y(x)]^2 + 1)}
$$

So looks like $y' = 0 \iff x = 0 \lor x^2 + [y(x)]^2 - 1 = 0$.

Now because of the constraints given on $y(x)$, $x \in (0, \sqrt{2}) \implies x \neq 0$.

Thus the only possible solution is $x^2 + [y(x)]^2 - 1 = 0$ which implies $x^2 + [y(x)]^2 + 1 = 2$ and $y(x) \neq 0$.

But how can I compute the exact $x$ value from this?

Comment: Isn't $$(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)=0$$ given?

Comment: Yes but how can I use this in the equation below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$y^2=1-x^2$$ we get $$1=2(x^2-(1-x^2))$$